# Use Glide or coil to display and caching generated bitmap

Tags: java, kotlin, caching, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I'm trying to optimize my recyclerview, I'm loading in pdf thumbnails generated from a function, I manage to display these bitmaps from a function which return me one’s but impossible to save them in the Glide cache. A new one is regenerated each time, I achieved this result using the piece of code bellow. The goal is to load the thumbnail from the cache if it already exists, otherwise generate it. I heard about signatures also with Glide but when I add this parameter I get an error... Also I heard about coil library which seems to offers this kind of features too.
Someone know how to do it?

Thank you

```
val bitmapPdf: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.resources,R.drawable.ic_pdf)

        Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(bitmapPdf).into(object : CustomTarget<Bitmap>() {
            override fun onLoadCleared(placeholder: Drawable?) {
            }

            override fun onResourceReady(
                resource: Bitmap,
                transition: com.bumptech.glide.request.transition.Transition<in Bitmap>?
            ) {
                val bitmapPdf = pdfToBitmap(currentFile)  //My bitmap generator
                holder.file_img.setImageBitmap(bitmapPdf)
            }

        })
```